# Append fields to Json record object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft's Json.Net.
I have this Json:

```
var j1 = {"status_code":"200", "message":"everything is ok"};
```

and this is the other Json:

```
var j2 = {"records":[{"id":"1", "name":"file1"},
                      {"id":"2", "name":"file2"},
                      {"id":"3", "name":"file3"}]
         };
```

Basically the second j2 is list (array) of files in a directory.
It might be empty:

```
 {"records":"[]"}
```

What I want: is to append (concat, merge) j2 to end of j1 like this:

```
var j3 = {
          "status_code":"200", 
          "message":"everything is ok", 
          "records":[{"id":"1", "name":"file1"},
                      {"id":"2", "name":"file2"},
                      {"id":"3", "name":"file3"}]
         };
         // NOTE: the array does NOT have double quots ("")
```

How can I accomplish this with JsonConvert.Serialize() or any other ways in Newtonesoft's Json.NET?

Comment: Can you please tell us what code you have written to achieve this?

Comment: It would help if you'd provide real code rather than pseudo-code... we don't know what you're using in terms of LINQ to JSON etc.

Comment: It's not duplicate. This is appending feilds to the Json object. Not merging. I haven't coded this

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

```
var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new[] { JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(j1), 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(j2) });
```

or

```
var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { obj1 = JObject.Parse(j1), 
                                          obj2 = JObject.Parse(j2) });
```

Comment: Have tried this. This will generate a different result: {obj1 = {"status..."}, obj2 = "records:..."}

Comment: This doesn't result in what the OP asked for...

Answer (score 0):

Might try this (note: no null checking whatsoever...):

```
string json1 = "{\"status_code\":\"200\",\"message\":\"everything is ok\"}";
string json2 = "{\"records\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"file1\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"file2\"},{\"id\":\"3\",\"name\":\"file3\"}]}";

dynamic object1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json1);
dynamic object2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json2);

dynamic result = object1;
result.records = object2.records;

string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Comment: This is really inefficient and uses `dynamic` when it's completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
var j3 = j1.concat(j2);
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers are vastly over complicating things... Just create a new anonymous type inline where you call SerializeObject, it would look something like this;

```
  string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { status_code = j1.status_code, 
                                                        message = j1.message,
                                                        records = j2.records } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using JSON.NET built in LINQ to JSON:

```
string j1 = {"status_code":"200", "message":"everything is ok"};
string j2 = {"records":[{"id":"1", "name":"file1"},
                          {"id":"2", "name":"file2"},
                          {"id":"3", "name":"file3"}]
             }; 

JObject jObject1 = JObject.Parse(j1);
JObject jObject2 = JObject.Parse(j2);

jObject1.Merge(jObject2, new JsonMergeSettings
                {
                    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Concat
                });

string j3 = jObject1.ToString();
```

The `j3` variable will look exactly like this:

```
{
    "status_code": "200",
    "message": "everything is ok",
    "records": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "file1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "file2"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "file3"
        }
    ]
}
```

which is what you wanted.